# Boost Interprocess sharing a vector causes strange deadlock (full code sample)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, condition-variable

I am sharing a `boost::interprocess::vector` across two processes, using a `boost::interprocess::named_mutex` and `boost::interprocess::named_condition`.

The reader begins first, obtaining the mutex and waiting for data to be written. The writer obtains the mutex, begins writing but **it hangs on the line where it updates the shared vector**.

If I run the program I get the following output:

```
Reader trying to get mutex
Reader waiting for data
Writer attempting to get mutex
Writer got mutex. Number of items to write: 2
Writing value: 1
```

The writer has two items to insert in the vector, but for some reason it stops after inserting the first and just hangs.

This is the code for the writer (full code further below):

```
void write(const std::vector<T>& items)
{
    std::cout << "Writer attempting to get mutex" << std::endl;

    scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(*mutex);
    {
        std::cout << "Writer got mutex. Number of items to write: " << items.size() << std::endl;

        for(const auto& item : items)
        {
            std::cout << "Writing value: " << item << std::endl;
            vec->push_back(item);   // <--------------------------- HANGS HERE -----
        }

        std::cout << "Writer notifying reader" << std::endl;
        cond_empty->notify_all();
    }

    std::cout << "Writer finished" << std::endl;
}
```

This is the full code (should be able to copy, paste and run):

```
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/named_condition.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> //std::system
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

template<typename T>
struct MySharedData
{
    using ShmemAllocator = allocator<T, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
    using MyVector = vector<T, ShmemAllocator>;

    MySharedData(const bool isConsumer, const std::string& sharedMemoryName, const std::string& blockName, const int numBytes) : shared_memory_name(sharedMemoryName), block_name(blockName)
    {
        is_consumer = isConsumer;
        segment.reset(new managed_shared_memory(open_or_create, sharedMemoryName.c_str(), numBytes));
        const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst(segment->get_segment_manager());

        vec = segment->find_or_construct<MyVector>(blockName.c_str())(alloc_inst);
        cond_empty.reset(new named_condition(open_or_create, sharedMemoryName.c_str()));
        mutex.reset(new named_mutex(open_or_create, sharedMemoryName.c_str()));
    }

    ~MySharedData()
    {
        if(is_consumer)
        {
            segment->destroy<MyVector>(block_name.c_str());
        }
    }

    void write(const std::vector<T>& items)
    {
        std::cout << "Writer attempting to get mutex" << std::endl;

        scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(*mutex);
        {
            std::cout << "Writer got mutex. Number of items to write: " << items.size() << std::endl;

            for(const auto& item : items)
            {
                std::cout << "Writing value: " << item << std::endl;
                vec->push_back(item);   // <--------------------------- HANGS HERE -----
            }

            std::cout << "Writer notifying reader" << std::endl;
            cond_empty->notify_all();
        }

        std::cout << "Writer finished" << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<T> read()
    {
        std::vector<T> toReturn;

        bool continue_trying = true;

        while(continue_trying)
        {
            std::cout << "Reader trying to get mutex" << std::endl;

            scoped_lock<named_mutex> lock(*mutex);
            {
                if(nullptr != vec )
                {
                    if(vec->empty())
                    {
                        std::cout << "Reader waiting for data" << std::endl;
                        cond_empty->wait(lock);
                        std::cout << "Reader notified of data" << std::endl;
                    }

                    for(auto& t : *vec)
                    {
                        std::cout << "Reading: " << t << std::endl;
                        toReturn.push_back(t);
                    }

                    continue_trying = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "No data to read from shared memory: " << shared_memory_name << " block: " << block_name << std::endl;
                    continue_trying = false;
                }
            }
        }

        std::cout << "Reader finished" << std::endl;

        return toReturn;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<named_mutex>            mutex{nullptr};
    MyVector*                               vec{nullptr};
    std::unique_ptr<managed_shared_memory>  segment{nullptr};
    std::unique_ptr<named_condition>        cond_empty;
    bool                                    is_consumer{false};
    std::string                             shared_memory_name;
    std::string                             block_name;
};

void parent()
{
    MySharedData<int> msd1(false, "a", "b", 100000);
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    msd1.write(vec);
}

void child()
{
    MySharedData<int> msd2(true, "a", "b", 100000);
    std::vector<int> x = msd2.read();
}

int main()
{
    shared_memory_object::remove("a");
    shared_memory_object::remove("b");
    shared_memory_object::remove("c");
    shared_memory_object::remove("d");
    named_mutex::remove("a");
    named_mutex::remove("b");
    named_mutex::remove("c");
    named_mutex::remove("d");
    named_condition::remove("a");
    named_condition::remove("b");
    named_condition::remove("c");
    named_condition::remove("d");

    // The below code spawns the parent method off to a separate process
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0)
    {
        //child();
        parent();
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        //parent();
        child();
    }

    std::cout << "FINISHED" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I have just tried calling vec->reserve(items.size()) before the writer loop and it hands here too

Comment: Doesn't seem to be 100% deterministic. Most of the time the bug displays, but occasionally the program works fine. Must be a race condition somewhere??

Comment: How is it possible that both reader and writer got lock on the same mutex? (from your output)

Comment: @AntonMalyshev The output is slightly misleading as there's also a [named condition variable](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_condition.html) being used.

Comment: If you kill the program holding the lock you will get this behaviour. Do you e.g. stop the debugger mid-process?

Comment: To all: there's a vector, mutex and condition variable all being shared across two processes

Comment: Probably unrelated but... the condition `if(vec->empty())` in `MySharedData::read` should probably be `while (vec->empty())` to protect against spurious wakeups from `cond_empty->wait(lock)`.

Comment: @G.M. Hi, sorry I don't understand how that would change the behaviour? If its empty the reader will wait()? Or is there a race condition between empty() and wait()?

Comment: Condition variables can, in general, be woken by events other than an explicit notification so it's important to make sure you always re-check the condition you were waiting on.  See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) for example.